# Override Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer is not working in custom module magento2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to override layer.php file in my custom module but it is not taking override file it is load core file only

Here is my di.xml file -> path : [namespace][module_name][etc] -> di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer" type="[namespace]\[module_name]\Model\Layer" />
```

here is my custom module layer.php file
Path : [namespace][module_name][Model][Layer.php]

namespace [namespace][module_name]\Model;

```
class Layer extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
{
    public function getProductCollection()
    {
          var_dump("local");
          die;
    }
}
```

When I run the code it is not load file from my custom module.

Can you please help me I am not getting how to load layer.php file from my custom module.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you solve it?